# Angular 15: How to get routed component in angular test

Tags: angular, testing

I want to test a routing service that manages state preserving that I have created. For this I want to check the states of components after some navigations. Basically, what I want to do is:

- Navigate to /path1
- Get component in /path1 and check some state
- Navigate to /path2
- Get component in /path2 and check some state
- Navigate back
- Check state of the component in path 1

Is this possible?